# URL rewrite results in a 404, but everything should work!

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

So I modified this code that I found elsewhere and stuck it in a plugin. The plugin works; I can see the .htaccess file updated when I hit save on the permalinks page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );

function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'microsoft/mcsa/',
        'wp-content/microsoft.php?cert=mcsa',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );

function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'cert';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /training/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^microsoft/mcsa/ /training/wp-content/microsoft.php?cert=mcsa [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /training/index.php [L]
```

I can go to /training/wp-content/microsoft.php?cert=mcsa and the page loads. But when I try to access it via /microsoft/mcsa, it does not and gives me a 404.

What gives? And is there any way to enable error logging to see where it's trying to go? Enabling debug mode in wp_config didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: At the root of the Wordpress install, same directory as wp-config, wp-settings, etc.

Comment: so, in `/training/` ?

Comment: Correct. It is in /training/

Comment: if you're visiting `/microsoft/mcsa/` not within the `/training/` directory, that htaccess file never gets parsed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The structure is such though: /training/microsoft/ and I'm trying to make /training/microsoft/mcsa access /training/wp-content/microsoft.php?params. I was under the assumption .htaccess remains at root? Is this not the case?

Comment: Also, I should probably make clear-- /training/microsoft/ is in itself a rewritten URL, not an actual directory on disk.

Comment: your question seems to contradict your comment, so you're trying to visit `/training/microsoft/mca/`? rather than try to do this via an external rewrite, it may be simpler to use an internal rewrite [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/81871/4771).

Comment: Internal rewrites may work, but is what I'm trying to do even possible? I have permalinks set up through WP. /training/microsoft points to a post titled "Microsoft." I want the user to be able to go to /training/microsoft/mcsa and go to a separate page of my own creation.

Comment: it should work if you get the rule correct. do you get a server 404 page, or a WordPress 404 page?

Comment: Wordpress 404...